# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, arraylist, hash, hashmap

I am trying to build new hashmap with arraylist from old hashmap, but I get this error

Error:

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

I know it is error with some initialisation but can not catch it

code

```
  nMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (String type: allTypes) {
            if (oData.get(type).size() > 0) {
                    arraySort(oData.get(type));
                    nData.get(type).add(fData.get(type).get(0).value);
               }
        }
```

OData is old hashmap that contains data for sure...

Comment: `cData` does not contain `type` (or the value associated to this key is null, but it is less likely). Use a debugger, and have a look in side `cData` to check which elements exactly does it contain.

Comment: cData.get(type) is returning null value

Comment: The map contains null elements, you have to "put" something in their.

Comment: yes, but how can I add first type and then update respective arraylist to each typ

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code.

```
if (nData.get(type) == null) {
    nData.put(type, new ArrayList<>());
}
nData.get(type).add(fData.get(type).get(0).value);
```